# JSONDecodeError Expecting value

Tags: python, json, api, python-requests

I am trying to get json object, and it tells me it's expecting a value even though i define the path to the json in r.json(). Also when i do r.headers[content-type] give me text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1 ... Thank you for your time everyone

```
import requests
import json

session = requests.Session()
username = "------"
password = "-------"
url_cookie = 'http://ludwig.podiumdata.com:----/podium/j_spring_security_check?j_username=--&j_password=----'
url_get = 'http://ludwig.corp.podiumdata.com:----/qdc/entity/v1/getEntities?type=EXTERNAL&count=2&sortAttr=name&sortDir=ASC'
r = requests.get(url_get, auth=(username,password), verify=False)
r.json()

r.headers['content-type']
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-108-61f8159bb1b5>", line 10, in <module>
    r.json()

  File "//anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 897, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)

  File "//anaconda3/lib/python3.7/json/__init__.py", line 348, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)

  File "//anaconda3/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())

  File "//anaconda3/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None

JSONDecodeError: Expecting value
```

Answer (score 0):

Your request is receiving the response as `text/html`, but you want to receive `application/json`.

You need to include {'Accept': 'application/json'} as a header in your request.

Example: `requests.get(url_get, auth=(username,password), headers={'Accept': 'application/json'}, verify=False)`

Also, it looks like you aren't using the Session you created on line 3, but that isn't what is causing this error.

Comment: You are correct.. i get the text/html from the login page of my ui but it completely ignores the auth parameter ...im guessing i have to use that session method to keep the session open somehow but not sure how.